# Both have suite cases or a suite case

Tags: word-usage, usage

Say there are two people waiting in an airport lobby. Each of them has a suite case. Which is correct - Both have suite cases OR Both have a suite case?

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Both), both indicates that the action or state denoted by the verb applies individually to each of two entities. So the correct sentence is:

Both have a suitcase.

Look at another sentence as follows:

Both of us are married.

The sentence means that each of us is married, not we are married to each other.

Comment: More likely, they both have suitcases.  (At any rate, I don't know what suite cases are . . . )

Comment: snailboat, I am sorry it's a suitcase not a suite case.

Answer (score 1):

Both can have either one suitcase or two suitcases as they wish.As you explained that there were two suitcases, you should say "Both have suitcases ".Both =two.